# .Net Specific PerfMon Counter Missing

Tags: c#, .net-framework, perfmon

I do have another issue with Perfmon data. On below screen you can see my Prod Box has all .Net Perfmon Data available while on Dev box it's missing.

[image: Prod Perfmon With .Net Counters]

[image: Dev Perfmon with missing .Net Counters]

[image: Registry Value for Dev Box]

I thought it could be missing Registry value as indicated by some Google search result (Please see attached image). But still no luck. I looked from 32bit/64bit  angle but still no output. Both machines are running on "Windows Server DataCenter" OS. Any expert insight on why it might be causing such weird issue is highly appreciated. If you need more info to gain further insight please let me know and I can provide you same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to manually rebuild Performance Counter Library as described in this link:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;300956

Comment: Thanks for URL !! It gave me right direction. I found below post useful as well since it resolves same question with shorter description to read. I hope it will help some other troubled users like me :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540777/performancecounters-on-net-4-0-windows-7